# Injecting existing logger in the Hosted Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, serilog, ilogger

I am having the project in .net core 3.1. I have configured to use the SeriLog as logger.

One of the service `MqttComunicationClient` is having logger injected to constructor which is using the serilog configuration. Here `ILogger` is `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

```
public MqttCommunicationClient(
            IMqttCommunicationConfiguration mqttConfiguration,
            ILogger logger,
            )
        {
            this.mqttConfiguration = mqttConfiguration;
            this.logger = logger;            
        }
```

From the `Init` method of this class I am initializing the custom written MQTT API.

```
public void Initialize()
        {
            var mqttClientId = $"{DefaultClientIdPattern}{Environment.MachineName}";

            serviceHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                  .UseMQTTApi(opt =>
                  {                          
                      opt.UserName = "test";
                      opt.Password = "test";
                  })
                  .ConfigureServices(services =>
                  {
                      services.AddSingleton(logger);                           
                  })
                  .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c => { c.Build(); })
                  .Start();

            managedMqttClient = serviceHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IManagedMqttClient>();
        }
```

My MQTT Api is having the Handlers which will be triggered on the message received on specified topic.

One of the handler is having following constructor.

```
public ConnectionStatusHandler(
         ILogger<ConnectionStatus> logger,
         IDeviceCommunications deviceCommunications)         
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.deviceCommunications = deviceCommunications;
        }
```

Now the issue is when I debug my `MqttComunicationClient` the logger is configured as the `SeriLog`. As per the requirment and configuration `logger.LogInformation()` used inside this class is logging to the log file.

[image]

When the `ConnectionStatusHandler` is called the `logger` changes to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger` Logger.

[image]

The logger used in `ConnectionStatusHandler` class is only logging to the console and not in the file.

How can I pass on the same serilog configured `logger` object from `MqttComunicationClient` to the `ConnectionStatusHandler` ?
Do I need some additional settings? I am a new to this so any help is appreciated.

**Edits**
Code which is configuring the `serilog` as logger

```
public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(string basePath)
  {
     var configuration = GetConfiguration(basePath);
     
     var logger = CreateLogger(configuration);
     var services = new ServiceCollection();
     services.AddSingleton(logger);
     return services.BuildServiceProvider();
  }

protected virtual ILogger CreateLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
     return LogBuilder.CreateLogger(null, configuration);
  }
  
// Serilog configured here
public static ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName, IConfiguration configuration, Action<string> selfLogAction = null)
  {
     var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                           .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                           .CreateLogger();

     using (var serilogLoggerProvider = new SerilogLoggerProvider(serilogLogger))
     {
        var logger = serilogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger(categoryName);

        if (selfLogAction != null)
        {
           Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(selfLogAction);
        }

        return logger;
     }
  } 

// This method reads the configuration from the config json file.
protected virtual IConfiguration GetConfiguration(string basePath)
  {
     StringBuilder configLog = null;
     var mainConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(basePath)
        .AddJsonFile("mytest.config.json")
        .Build();
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     return BuildConfiguration(builder, mainConfiguration, basePath, configLog)
        .Build();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share the dependency injection setup code (normally in Startup.cs file)?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I have added the code under Edits. This code resides in a separate common project called "BaseServiceProvider". We are using this for the common configuration of the service. Thank you.

Comment: Two separate service collections and thus providers are being used.

Comment: Are you able to recreate this scenario in simpler app, so we can see more of your app? I have some clues on what might be the thing, but it would be much more helpful to actually see the code and not just snippets out of context

Comment: @DominikSzymański yes its behavior is same for other application also. It uses the same code I posted above nothing changed.. Can you please hint what you are guessing the problem is?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is currently setting up requests for `ILogger` (untyped) to resolve to Serilog, but `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is setting up `ILogger<T>` to work with Microsoft's Logger.

I'd recommend using [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting#serilogextensionshosting--) to handle your Serilog registration, that way you can just add `UseSerilog()` to your hostbuilder and be done.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how can I add exiting serilog configured ILogger object inside the UseSerilog()? I want the same logging configuration.

Comment: This package includes 3 signatures with a variety of parameters. One of them does allow you to [pass in an ILogger](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L56). Others allow you to build the config with `Action<HostBuilderContext, LoggerConfiguration> configureLogger` or `Action<HostBuilderContext, IServiceProvider, LoggerConfiguration>`. You could put such an action in a central location.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Serilog Hosting package handles the `ILogger`/`ILogger<T>` piece by replacing the Microsoft `ILoggerFactory` With `SerilogLoggerFactory` from [Serilog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging). The source for both of these packages is at least relatively small, it might be worth the time to read through them

Comment: @Tim, UseSerilog doesn't configure `ILogger` by default, only `ILogger<T>`. But that's just minor thing otherwise your answer is exactly the solution, I was thinking about it, but couldn't get to that exact piece (as Serilog requires multiple things to be configured). Good job at providing that solution :)